# Troubleshooting Python YouTube-download script

Tags: python, youtube

I have been using [youtube-dl](http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/src) for a while now with no issues, but now I keep getting an error saying

> ERROR: unable to download video (format may not be available) for all videos.

What may the issue be?

Comment: There's no src in that link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with the most current version of yt-dl, which can be found here:

http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/download.html

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue like the following and made it working.

Note: using the below mentioned command twice is mandatory, I think. I tried it once only, but it didn't work so after executing this command twice it really worked.

Simply type the following command twice in your terminal window with administrator permissions.

```
sudo youtube-dl -U

sudo youtube-dl -U
```

The first update fetches the GitHub version, while the second update retrieves the version 2011.03.29 which really worked for me.

The stuff provided here is not my own, but I found *[Youtube-dl - Download videos from youtube in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-download-videos-from-youtube-in-ubuntu.html)* from some other site, and I think this may also work for you.